# VSCode Run Button for Python does not show correct output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have this wierd situation in which if I type `python maximum_sum.py` in the terminal, the program runs successfully.

But if I use the button provided by the code runner extension in VSCode to run my code, it doesn't give me an output.

[image: The last line shows my output after clicking on the run button]

I tried reinstalling the code runner extension but it still doesn't work.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: just check the python versions are same for `python --version` and `python3 --version`, your vs code is using python3

Comment: `python --version` shows output as Python3.7.0 but `python3 --version` doesn't show any output

Comment: @Mihir It is recommended that you try to comment out the code-runner settings and disable other non-essential extensions.